# Python Cerberus JSON schema validation

Tags: python, json, schema, cerberus

I have no clue why my code doesn't work, hence looking for some help.

That's my sample JSON **array**:

```
[
    {
        "bookingid": 1774
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 1020
    }
]
```

and my code is as follows:

```
def test_get_booking_ids_correct_schema():
    schema = {
        "type": "array",
        "items":
            {
                "properties":
                    {
                        "bookingid":
                            {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    response = requests.get("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking")
    response_body = response.json()

    v = Validator(schema)
    is_valid = v.validate(response_body)

    assert is_valid == True
```

and  the error I'm getting is as follows:

```
        if not self.schema_validator(test_schema, normalize=False):
>           raise SchemaError(self.schema_validator.errors)
E           cerberus.schema.SchemaError: {'items': [{'properties': ['unknown rule']}], 'type': ['must be of dict type']}
```

Do you see any obvious mistake in my schema?

On the contrary, the code below works perfectly fine:

```
def test_temp():
    schema = {"origin": {"type": "string"}}
    json = {
        "origin": "185.21.87.131"
    }

    v = Validator(schema)
    is_valid = v.validate(json)

    assert is_valid == True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to validate a document which is an array as root element. As you can see on : https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/issues/220

by the way, the type `array` didn't exist in the Cerberus schema, you should use `list` instead.